# SQL Server 2008 is showing the SQL Server 2000 Version Number

Tags: sql-server

We've got a server with SQL Server 2008 installed, but if we run:

```
SELECT @@version
```

or, as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

the version number is reported as **8.0.2055** - I'm pretty sure that the server used to have SQL Server 2000 installed but was upgraded about a year ago.

Has anyone come across anything like this before? If so, how do you get SQL Server 2008 to report the correct version number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you certain you're connecting to the right instance of SQL Server? It sounds like your server has two instances (one under SQL2000) running.